# How to preg_match inside array / arraylist

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

Ho i can get the value of arrays inside arraylist with pregmatch?
i have array like this

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [judul] => extrahorror[data] => Array(
            [url] => url - horror[embed] => embed - horror
        )
    ) [1] => Array(
        [judul] => extraadventure[data] => Array(
            [url] => url - adventure[embed] => embed - adventure
        )
    ) [2] => Array(
        [judul] => music[data] => Array(
            [url] => url - music[embed] => embed - music
        )
    )
)
```

i want `preg_match` that the title contain 'extra' and get the `data->url` and `data->embed`

i was browsing the stack history no 1 found if anybody can found let me know or answer this please

Comment: What is your exact expected output?

Comment: array([0] =>array([title]=>{filtered title} [url]=>url [embed]=>embed ))

is it posible to get like this?

Comment: Can you show your php code @HandriandProExcalibur

Comment: i got this array from google api v2 then i parse it with this code
foreach($all_files->items as $files){
    $links[] = array('title' => $files->title, 'data'=>array('url' => $files->selfLink, 'embed' => $files->embedLink));
}
print_r($links);
nah i want get the specific title contain some word for filtering
this data after parse https://pastebin.com/xZL59Pjx
and this before i parse with it https://pastebin.com/fnf2vztT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with one loop

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $x) {
    // if a title contains 'extra'
    if( preg_match('~extra~', $x['judul'])) {
        // collect to an inner array
        $x['data']['judul'] = $x['judul'];
        // add to the result array
        $res[] = $x['data'];
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/40ff54d06f0c3512f8db201cc0540049d0a383bb)

Comment: i think its not my array becouse my array like this
https://pastebin.com/xZL59Pjx

Comment: Try now and if  it will not work  put your array by var_export()

Comment: O_o its work like a magic XD ty sir , can you explain what is var_export() usage?

Comment: The only change i made- replace `title` with `judul` :)))

Comment: how i can made that judul at first on array results instead of url?
dont change it its made out of topic. make it title again or i got -rep by stack again.

Comment: it has no matter for associative array. But `$res[] = [ 'judil'=>$x['judul'], 'url'=>$x['data']['url'], 'embed'=>$x['data']['embed']];`

Comment: ahh after we got the filtered array then we choose whatever result after filtered like we get data from arrays, ahh new experience ty sir.